# Chain rule in differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose we have a coordinate transformation such that $x=f(r), y=g(r)$ What I want, is to transform a differential with respect to $x$ and $y$ to one with respect to $r$.

I know,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} $

My problem here is that the two separate terms individually give $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ just like in the case of one dimension. So, why do we need to consider the partials with respect to both of the terms ? Shouldn't we do it with respect to either $x$ or $y$ instead of both ?

I'm clearly lacking a theoretical understanding, and probably treating the differential as a fraction which is clearly wrong. However, any explanation on this would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. The "differential with respect to x and y" clearly must contain both x and y, and their rate of change depends on the rate of change of r (since that's how you defined them). That's why all those terms are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assume you have a scalar function $z = f(x,y)$. Now, you just want to focus onto a single curve in the plane say $[x(r),y(r)]$ where $r$ is any parameter. For example $x = \cos(r), y =\sin(r)$ is a circle for $0\leq r\leq 2\pi$. Hence, computing $\frac{dz}{dr}$ would give you the rate of chance of $z$ along the curve you parametrized before. Evidently, the curve may not vary only in $x$ or in $y$ (for example in the case of the circle). Thus, to compute $\frac{dz}{dr}$ we need to take into account both contributions. Now, some remarks

- First, why do we write $\frac{dz}{dr}$ and not $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$: the thing is that as soon as you "specialized" to one curve $[x(r),y(r)]$ you no longer have two independent variables as before. Instead you have a single independent variable $r$ and $x,y$ depend on it (the same for $z$). Hence, $\frac{dz}{dr}$ is the "total derivative" of $z$ wrt $r$.
- In contrast $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ are called the partial derivatives since the are used to compute the rate of change of $z$ in the $x,y$ directions by separate but for the whole space, not only to the curve. Thus, when not in a single curve, $x,y$ are still independent.
- Now, the formula for the total derivative:
  $$
  \frac{dz}{dr} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dr}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dr}
  $$
  Note the differences between this and what you wrote. Note that we write $\frac{dy}{dr}$ and not $\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$ since $y(r)$ depends on a single variable. Note that this correct notation empathizes the fact that you cannot "cancel" $\partial x$ with $dx$ or $\partial y$ with $dy$.

Final remark: intuitively "canceling" differentials usually only works with a single variable. In the vector case, you cannot do that; this is stressed by the fact that the notation of a total/single-variable derivative is different from the one of a partial derivative. Make sure not to confuse them.

Moreover, if the curve we parameterized varied only along the $x$ axis for example: $[x(r),c]$ with $c$ constant, thus $\frac{dy}{dr}=0$ and you would get $\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dr}$ as you wanted. But this is a very particular case. In general you need the two contributions.

Hope this helps.